# How to add expression to plot legend label with %in% and %~%

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add a legend in R with a math expression in it.
I'm trying to have the \in (LaTeX notation) via the following code
expression(paste("Prior ",beta[3] %in%," (-0.1 0.1)"))

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of `as.expression()` and `bquote()` instead:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(30),y=rnorm(30))

ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,col='blue')) +
  scale_color_manual("Legend",
                     values='blue',
                     labels=as.expression(bquote('Prior'~beta[3]%in%'(-0.1 0.1)')))
```

Output:

[image]